# Solve $(2z-1)^5 - i = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Solve $(2z-1)^5 - i = 0$

I started by saying that $(2z-1)^5  = i$

$(2z-1)  = \sqrt[5]i$

$z  =$ $(\sqrt[5]i +1) \over 2$

$z^5  =$ $(i +1) \over 32$

$z^5  =$ $1 \over32$$ *(i +1)$

From there, it's quite simple.. showing $z^5$ as $r^5Cis(5o)$ with da-muaver and showing $(1+i)$ as $\sqrt2 $$ Cis({\phi\over 4})$

Comment: Yeah. Find all the answers to that equation. If my way is right - no need to solve at all, it's quite simple after what I wrote.

Comment: your last paragraph is not clear... do you mind to edit that...

Comment: $x\mapsto \sqrt[5]{x}$ is not defined for complex numbers.

Comment: Well... $i^{1/5} = cis(\pi/2)^{1/5} = cis(\pi/10 + 2\pi k/5) = (*)$ by de Moivre's. So, $z = \frac{1+(*)}{2}$. But note that there are **five** roots so guessing/verifying **one** solution is not sufficient.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in Phraphulla's answer. Thanks you for confirming!! @ChrisK

Comment: Now I need to compute for $k = 0,...,4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

$\cos \theta+i\sin \theta=\sqrt[5]{i}\Rightarrow (\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)^5=i\Rightarrow \cos 5\theta+i\sin5\theta=i\Rightarrow \theta = ??$

Comment: So after I solve that, I need to solve seperately $(2z-1)$? and then the answers I got from what you just wrote and from $(2z-1)$ are the answers that solve the question?

Comment: Yes... Once you find what $\theta$ is you just have to write $2z-1=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta\Rightarrow z=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)$

Comment: I will solve and upload to here.

Comment: I got that $\theta = {{\phi + 4\phi k} \over {10}}$ Is that right?

Comment: Then, I write that $z = {1 + cis{\phi +4\phi k} \over {10}}*{{1} \over {2}}$ and from there I need to compute for $k = 0,1,2,3,4$

Comment: $\phi = 180 degrees$ , $k$ is a number from $0$ to $4$

Comment: That's it, I got the answer right. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't I? by using $k = 0,...,4$ I get all the 5 answers.

Comment: I mean, I'll get the 5 roots.

Comment: Oh.. I hate computing, I just want to understand the way to get to the "final form" before I calculate it.

Comment: It is up to you... Good luck! Delete those comments which are not necessary just to make this answer look clean.. I am deleting my comments which are unnecessary..

Comment: Life is too short for that.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that

$$i=\exp\left(\frac {i\pi}2\right)$$
so 
$$Z^5=i\iff Z=\exp\left(\frac {i\pi}{10}+\frac{2ik\pi}{5}\right),\quad k=0,\ldots,4$$
Now let $Z=2z-1$ and solve the given equation for $z$.

Comment: Didn't study "exp", can't use it. It's a part of my linear-algebra and we studied really the basics of complex numbers. We are allowed to use $z = a +ib$ if that helps somehow.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS $\exp(x)\equiv e^x$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS, you use **cis**, where $cis(x) = \exp(ix)$ by de Moivre's.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks! didn't know that.